# Does web scraping have patterns?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have not done too much of web scraping in my experience. So far I am using python and using `BeautifulSoup4` to scrape the hackernews page.

Was just wondering if there are patterns I should keep in mind before doing scraping. Right now the code looks very ugly and I feel like a hack.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Command(BaseCommand):

page = {}
td_count = 2
data_count = 0

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    for i in range(1,4):
        self.page_no = i
        self.parse()
    print self.page[1]


def get_result(self): 
    return requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/news?p=%s'% self.page_no)

def parse(self):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(self.get_result().text, 'html.parser')
    for x in soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr'):
        self.data_count += 1 
        self.page[self.data_count] = {'other_data' : None, 'url' : ''}
        if self.td_count%3 == 0:
            try:
                subtext = x.find_all('td','subtext')[0]
                self.page[self.data_count - 1]['other_data'] = subtext
            except IndexError:
                pass

        title = x.find_all('td', 'title')
        if title:
            try:
                self.page[self.data_count]['url'] = title[1].a
                print title[1].a
            except IndexError:
                print 'Done page %s'%self.page_no
        self.td_count +=1
```

Comment: Why not try [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) ?

Comment: If I am not wrong,its non-MIT ? I will try it out though

Answer (score 4):

Actually I behave scrappable data as part of my domain(business) data, which allows me to use Domain Driven Design to structure the problem:

**Entities and Value Objects**

I use entities and value objects to store the correct extracted information from data into my programming language data structures, so I can work with them in a great way.

**Repository Pattern**

I use repository pattern to delegate the job of gathering data to a different class. The repository class is given a site and then fetches the data and pre-builds the entities if needed.

**Transformer/Presenter pattern**

After fetching the data from the repository, I pass the html data to a presenter class. The presenter class has the duty of creating my business entity/value objects from the given HTML string.

**Service Layer**

If there is more process than those described above, I make a service class which is a wrapper around the problem, It calls the repository , gives the fetched data to the presenter the presenter builds the entities, and done, the result may be used by another service to be stored in a SQL database.

If you are familiar with PHP, I have programmed a small app in Laravel which fetches the alexa rank of a given website each 15mins and notifies the subscribers of that website by Email.

- Github repository : [Alexa Watcher](https://github.com/reshadman/alexa-watcher)
- [Folder of Repository classes](https://github.com/reshadman/alexa-watcher/tree/master/app/Repositories)
- [Command line application layer class which calls the service](https://github.com/reshadman/alexa-watcher/blob/master/app/Console/Commands/AlexaWatcher.php)
- [The Service class which is also a presenter that builds needed entities.](https://github.com/reshadman/alexa-watcher/blob/master/app/Services/AlexaFetcher.php)
- [The Service class which pushes detected changes to subscriber emails.](https://github.com/reshadman/alexa-watcher/blob/master/app/Services/AlexaFetcher.php)

Comment: All the links show a 404 error. You either deleted them or changed your Github's username